# CSS input height in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

If I create an `input` with the following CSS

```
input {
  border: none;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I excpect a height of 16px of `input`, but the Chrome Developer Tools shows a height of 18px.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools calculated box model]

In Firefox the height is 16px.

What causes the additional 2px in Chrome?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fh7upk0n/

**I know that I have to use height if I want a fixed height, but I'm wondering where the 2px comes from.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that Chrome add 1px up and 1px down to make the text readable.

Of course you can force chrome to show a 16px height input by adding

```
height: 16px;
```

But as always, do not count on `line-height` to size un underlying element.

Answer (score 4):

you should use **height** instead of **line-height**

> **height-** the vertical measurement of the container
>
> **line-height-** the distance from the top of the first line of text to the top of the second

Comment: I agree. Line-height does not behave the same way in `<input>` fields. By explicitly setting the height value, then you can be more confident that it will appear the same height across browsers too.

Comment: I know that I have to use height if I want a fixed height, but I'm wondering where the 2px comes from.

Comment: You can see the difference here: https://jsfiddle.net/fh7upk0n/2/. 
Probably Chrome adds the 2px by default

Answer (score 1):

`height` = `font-size` and `box-sizing: content-box;`

```
input {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 0;
}
```